# How to find formula from scatterplot?

Tags: polynomials

I have a data about the correlation between the time and iteration of computer program.

This is the data:

- to perform 100000 iterations, computer needs 1000000 nanoseconds.
- to perform 200000 iterations, computer needs 2000000 nanoseconds
- to perform 300000 iterations, computer needs 2000000 nanoseconds
- to perform 400000 iterations, computer needs 2000000 nanoseconds
- to perform 500000 iterations, computer needs 3000000 nanoseconds
- to perform 600000 iterations, computer needs 3000000 nanoseconds
- to perform 700000 iterations, computer needs 3000000 nanoseconds
- to perform 800000 iterations, computer needs 3000000 nanoseconds
- to perform 900000 iterations, computer needs 3000000 nanoseconds
- to perform 1000000 iterations, computer needs 3000000 nanoseconds

Now, lets, make a graph based on this data:

How to find formula of this black line, based on this image:
[image]

`nanoseconds = m.looping + b` ???

Please explain to me in easy way. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: no different than finding the equation of a line through two points.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the line connecting two points $(x_A,y_A),\ (x_B,y_B)$ in a cartesian plane is $$(x_B-x_A)(y-y_A)-(y_B-y_A)(x-x_A)=0$$ Since in your case $x_B-x_A\ne0$, you can rewrite it in $y=mx+p$ form with $m=\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}$ and $p=\frac{y_Ax_B-y_Bx_A}{x_B-x_A}$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, just find the formula based on this 2 points:

x=100000, y=1000000 
x=1000000, y=3000000

Then, calculate it using cartesian formula:
$$y-y_0=\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}(x-x_0) $$

$$ y-1000000=\frac {3000000-1000000}{1000000-100000}(x-100000)$$

$$ y-1000000=\frac{2000000}{900000}(x-100000)$$

$$ y-1000000=\frac{20}{9}(x-100000)$$

$$ y-1000000=\frac{20x}{9}-\frac{2000000}{9}$$

$$ y=\frac{20x}{9}-\frac{2000000}{9} + 1000000$$

$$ y=\frac{20x}{9}-\frac{2000000}{9} + \frac{9000000}{9}$$

$$ y=\frac{20x}{9}+\frac{7000000}{9}$$

$$ y=\frac{20}{9}(x+350000)$$

final answer: $$ nanoseconds=\frac{20}{9}(looping+350000)$$